# How to use variable define in python in flask application

Tags: python, flask

I am using in my.py file. Here I need to difene posts varible from CVS file.
Here is my code:

```
  from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
        
    
        
        
    app = Flask(__name__)
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.read_csv('data_ids.csv')
    posts=[]
    for i in range(len(df)):
        posts.append( {
            
            
            'name': df.iloc[i]['name'],
            'Last_name': df.iloc[i]['Last_name']
            
                        
                
        })
        
        
        
        
   @app.route("/")
   @app.route("/home")
   def home():

       return render_template('my.html', posts=posts)
        
        
    
        
        
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            app.run(debug=True)
```

It gives me the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

How to use already defined variable in flask.

Comment: You never set a value for `posts`. And BTW globals don't work that well in WSGI applications.

Comment: ' posts '  variable already exist in my variable explorer

Comment: Your variable explorer is lying to you. `posts` is marked as `global` but it is not initialized.

Comment: I update my problem

Comment: what is the output of `pip list`, seems as if `pandas` is not installed.

Comment: @marcelh that was the problem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author has edited the question to represent a new different issue.